# How to replace JSON value using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

This is my JSON file
sample.json

```
{
  "lbl_name":"Your name",
  "dynamic_name":"Hi, {{ name 1 }}, {{ name 2 }} and {{ name 3 }}"
}
```

and

```
$content = file_get_contents(sample.json);
$translate = json_decode$content, true);
$replaceContent = preg_replace('/\{{[^)]*\}}/', '%s', $translate);
print_r($replaceContent);
```

I am getting result

```
Array ( [lbl_name] => Your name [dynamic_name] => Hi %s )
```

I want result should be

```
Array ( [lbl_name] => Your name [dynamic_name] => Hi %s, %s and %s )
```

Thanks

Comment: Make your regex not greedy: `*` -> `*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your regex is greedy, therefore trying to match the *biggest* match it can get.

use the `?`-control character to make your pattern non-greedy, meaning it matches the *smallest* match it can get:

```
$data = "Hi, {{ name 1 }}, {{ name 2 }} and {{ name 3 }}"
echo preg_replace('/{{[^)]*?}}/', '%s', $data);
//prints Hi, %s, %s and %s
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```
$data = '{
  "lbl_name":"Your name",
  "dynamic_name":"Hi, {{ name 1 }}, {{ name 2 }} and {{ name 3 }}"
}';

$data = json_decode($data, true);

$dynamic_name = $data['dynamic_name'];
$lbl_name = $data['lbl_name'];

preg_match_all('/{{ (.*?) }}/', $dynamic_name, $display);
$dynamic_name = "Hi ".$display[1][0].", ".$display[1][1]." and ".$display[1][2]; 

$newArray = array('lbl_name'=> $lbl_name, 'dynamic_name'=>$dynamic_name);
print_r($newArray);
```